# What is the name for a quadtree/octree like tree with an arbitrary number of child nodes?

Tags: data-structures, graphics, 3d, tree, octree

So if a node has 2*2 subnodes it is called a quadtree (2*2=4). If a node has 2*2*2 subnodes it is called an octree (2*2*2=8). Therefore if you work in 2D it is often good to use a quadtree and in 3D it is good practise to use an octree.

But are there any trees with an arbitrary number of subnodes in 3D? Like a tree with n*n*n subnodes. What is it called and are there any scientific works already for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A tree with three children per node is called a ternary tree. With 16 children per node would likely be called a hex tree. Beyond that, you'd probably just use the number: a 32-tree would have 32 children per node, etc. As for uses, I suppose if you were working in 6 dimensions, a 64-tree might come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want the k-D tree:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: k-d trees are actually binary -- two children per node, though they can handle an arbitrary number of dimensions (but each node is only dealing with one dimension).